# Update TextBox from second class with asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have read through a few threads here, but have not come to any conclusion.

An asynchronous method in another class is to be executed by button click.
In this method the current state should be added again and again in a text field of the form:

```
public interface MainForm {
    string LogText { get; set; }
}

public partial class KatalogForm : Form, MainForm {
public string LogText {
        get { return rtbxLog.Text; }
        set { rtbxLog.Text += value; }
    }

private void btnCreateCatalogues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Task.Run(() => catalogues.Create());
    }
}
```

Excerpt from the second class:

```
private static MainForm mainForm;
public async void Create() {
        //Stuff
        //Update TextBox
    }
```

Since the method is asynchronous, I can't access the textbox directly here.
I know that I have to work with Invoke here, but I can't implement this properly.
What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you return a `Task` in your `Create()` method and await it in the event handler of your button?

Comment: In `Create()` further asynchronous methods are called, which process different files simutaniously. Until everything is processed, it takes about 8 minutes.

Comment: What you want to add into TextBox?

Comment: If only complete message, you can use like this
`Task.Run(async () => {
await catalogues.Create();
//add complete message to textbox;
});`

Comment: Well, in this specific case entries from different files are processed. For each processed entry, a corresponding note should be displayed in the log. It shall be used as a kind of "status display".

Comment: The problem is that the form does not notice when individual entries have been processed. In the second class the processing of the documents is triggered - in a third class the entries are processed asynchronously. The processed lists are then stored in variables of the second class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when I have to asynchronously update a TextBox with data from external sources (ex: an operations log) I use a queue and a timer (Windows.Forms).
The method called by external objects adds the new data.
The timer clears pending data at a reasonable rate and updates the text box.

The advantages are:

- **Fast requests**: The update method invoked by external sources only add items to the queue.
- **Thread safe**: The text box is only updated within its own UI thread, so no cross-thread errors can occur.
- **Less allocations**: No Task or BeginInvoke calls are required, avoiding allocation of temporary objects.
- **Few UI updates**: The items are applied to the text box as batches (multiple items at the same time) based on the timer frequency.
- **First-in/First-out**: No risk of overlap of items due to asynchronous operations scheduled and executed in the wrong order.

See the sample class (*LogBox* user control) below, split into LogBox.cs and LogBox.Designer.cs:
Other objects would call `Log` method.
The default rate is 100ms; that is, 10 times a second (for a human reader should be enough).

Sample code (**LogBox.cs**):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SAMPLE
{
    [Docking(DockingBehavior.Ask)]
    public partial class LogBox : UserControl
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> PendingLog = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        public LogBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tmrLog_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.ProcessPendingLog(); }

        private void ProcessPendingLog()
        {
            if (!this.Disposing && !this.IsDisposed && this.IsHandleCreated)
                try
                {
                    if (!this.PendingLog.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        string item;
                        while (this.PendingLog.TryDequeue(out item))
                        {
                            txtLog.AppendText(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
        }

        public void Log(string text) { this.PendingLog.Enqueue(text); }
    }
}
```

Sample code (**LogBox.Designer.cs**):

```
namespace SAMPLE
{
    partial class LogBox
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.tmrLog = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.txtLog = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tmrLog
            // 
            this.tmrLog.Enabled = true;
            this.tmrLog.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrLog_Tick);
            // 
            // txtLog
            // 
            this.txtLog.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.txtLog.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.txtLog.Multiline = true;
            this.txtLog.Name = "txtLog";
            this.txtLog.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtLog.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
            this.txtLog.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.txtLog.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // LogBox
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtLog);
            this.Name = "LogBox";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrLog;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtLog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use `IProgress<string>` for catalogues.Create()

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
   var createProgress = new Progress<string>(ReportProgress);
   await catalogues.Create(createProgress);
});

void ReportProgress(string reportMessage)
{
  //update log here
}
```

usage inside `Create`

```
async Task Create(IProgress<string> progress)
{
   foreach (var category in categories)
   {
      // some staff
      progress.Report($"{category} - completed");
   }
}
```

[IProgress example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)