# Safely update a WinForms list control from several threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, .net-core, thread-safety

I have a .NET WinForms app in which I need to show messages from several instances of the [Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread) class executed simultaneously. The messages must be displayed in a list control (a list box or multi-column grid grid in the general case). The threads must be terminated correctly when the user clicks the close button of the form.

Let's suppose we have a [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox) control named listBox1 that displays messages from the threads. Here is the simplified version of the form's code for my question:

```c#
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread fThread1, fThread2, fThread3;
    int fMsgNo1, fMsgNo2, fMsgNo3;
    CancellationTokenSource fCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Thread1Body));
        fThread1.Start(fCTS.Token);

        fThread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Thread2Body));
        fThread2.Start(fCTS.Token);

        fThread3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Thread3Body));
        fThread3.Start(fCTS.Token);

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        fCTS.Cancel();

        fThread1.Join();
        fThread2.Join();
        fThread3.Join();

        fCTS.Dispose();

    }

    private void Thread1Body(object data)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)data;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            fMsgNo1++;
            listBox1.BeginInvoke(
                new AddMessageToListDelegate(AddMessageToList),
                new object[] { $"Thread 1 posted message {fMsgNo1}"});
        }
    }

    private void Thread2Body(object data)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)data;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            fMsgNo2++;
            listBox1.BeginInvoke(
                new AddMessageToListDelegate(AddMessageToList),
                new object[] { $"Thread 2 posted message {fMsgNo2}" });
        }
    }

    private void Thread3Body(object data)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)data;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            fMsgNo3++;
            listBox1.BeginInvoke(
                new AddMessageToListDelegate(AddMessageToList),
                new object[] { $"Thread 3 posted message {fMsgNo3}" });
        }
    }

    private delegate void AddMessageToListDelegate(string message);

    private void AddMessageToList(string message)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, message);
    }

}
```

It seems, this version of code works fine, but I am not completely sure. The problem that bothers me is that the previous version of this code used the [Invoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) method call instead of [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) to update the list box in the UI thread from the worker threads, and this caused a kind of block when the user clicked the close button. I found that in this case one of the worker threads may have waited endlessly for the end of execution of the method called with `Invoke`. As a result, one of the threads never ended, and the app hung on one of the [Thread.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join) calls in the form's Closing event handler. May this problem persist too if we use `Control.BeginInvoke()`?

If the problem can't be solved for the `Thread` class at all, can anybody suggest a better and robust template to implement what I need? Yes, I know that there are things like the [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) class that could be used for this task, but I'd like to know how to make the code works correctly for the `Thread` class first of all.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708861/5446495 with using custom usercontrol

Comment: You should really use `Task` and `await`. `Thread.Join` will block the message pump which is needed for `Invoke`, *never* use it on a UI thread.

Comment: @Charlieface, is `BeginInvoke` really free from this problem?

Comment: Partly and partly not. The other threads fire and forget, the UI thread just waits for them to finish before excuting the invoke. So it works sort of, but not how you think.

Comment: Instead of infinite `Join` in `OnFormClosing` I would suggest a non-blocking `Join(0)` in some `OnTimer` event handler.

Comment: `BeginInvoke()` here can solve *stuttering* caused by `Invoke()` if you invoke relatively often (not if you invoke the UI constantly, though), also possible deadlocks, since it won't wait for the call to be processed (and just enqueues the request to update the UI). It's not that different than passing (or capturing) a SynchronizationContext to `Post()` to a SendOrPostCallback (BackGroundWorker style, though this uses `[delegate].BeginInvoke()` to then start an AsyncOperation). BTW, you should change `listBox1.BeginInvoke()` in `this.BeginInvoke()` and `listBox1?.Items.Insert(0, message);`

Comment: <- In case the operations are simple as described here (you should also check the number of Items you're adding to that ListBox, otherwise it'll get *weird* after a while). -- If this kind of updates are limited to a specific Form, you can simplify running some Tasks (passing a `Progress<T>` delegate along with a CancellationToken) or using threaded Timers (depending on what actually replaces those `for` loops in real code).

Comment: @Jimi, the ListBox control was chosen just to demonstrate the concept and ask the question. In the real-world app we use a grid control with several columns instead of the list box. I am also worrying about grid update collisions when several threads initiate this operation because updating a grid involves about 10 calls of its members.

Comment: @Jimi, After reading all comments and examining the problem from different points of view, I come to a conclusion that the only reliable way of doing what I need is to use a `ConcurrentQueue` to enqueue messages from threads and a timer in the UI thread to query this queue - like @Genusatplay recommended in the very first comment. However, if you can post links to code snippets or samples based on Tasks, I'll be glad to consider them too.

Comment: As mentioned, this kind of solutions require a very clear context, not just *something* that *gives an idea*. -- Are you actually starting those Threads, or do you receive notifications through events raised in Threads other than the UI Thread (e.g., Video/Audio capture devices)? If not, do these Threads exist for the life-time of you app, or are just started when a specific Form is opened? Do these need to be foreground Threads as you're showing here? How often these Threads update the UI? Does the data need *treatment* or it's used as-is? Is the *sequence* important? etc.

Comment: If you have simple data that can be used directly to update a Control, calling `BeginInvoke()` is enough, this method simply enqueues messages in the Message Loop in the same sequence they're received, then processed when *their time* comes. Quite simple and effective, no deadlocks, not blocking. If you instead need to process the data before sending the result to the UI, you need a *collector* method that handles the queue, so a ConcurrentQueue or a Partitioner (if Task-based) can be a better choice. So, context.

Comment: @Jimi, the source code I posted is a simplified version of the app architecture. The only big difference is that the messages from the threads are records with several fields to be displayed in a grid control. I stopped at the `ConcurrentQueue`-based implementation, but still have one question regarding the `BeginInvoke` way. What happens if the window gets `WM_CLOSE` and a thread posts a message into the standard window message queue after that? In my understanding, it will be simply ignored and there is no need for `this.BeginInvoke()` and `listBox1?.Items.Insert()` as you suggested.

Comment: If the Form is closed while you still have messages in the Queue, the messages are not processed (thus discarded). It's assumed - based on your question - that this Form is responsible for starting the Threads, thus the only one responsible for collection the data (of course, you cannot - and doesn't make sense to - call `Invoke()` / `BeginInvoke()` if you don't have a marshaller Control) -- `this.BeginInvoke()` (the Form), not `[ChildControl].BeginInvoke()` because the Form is always the intended marshaller, `listBox1?.Items.Insert()` to avoid null-reference exceptions in different occasions.